# Get Count of Lazy Loaded Child Collection Using LINQ and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a class such as:

```
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public int ProductCount { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

I have a query that currently looks like this:

```
context.Categories.SortBy(sortByExpression).Skip(startRowIndex).Take(maximumRows)
```

I need to include the ProductCount field in my category grid. Is it possible to extend this LINQ query to give me the ProductCount property without reading in the entire Product collection? I can do this in a sub query using good old SQL, but I am stumped using LINQ.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is this roughly what you are looking for:

```
context.Categories.SortBy(sortByExpression).Skip(startRowIndex).Take(maximumRows)
    .Select(c => new { c.CategoryId, c.Name, ProductCount = c.Products.Count() });
```

or have I misunderstood your question?

*updated the code*

Comment: `ProductCount` is not mapped (note the attribte), thus can't be used to retrieve the value initially. I assume this property is where the result of that query will be stored.

Comment: I see, well then the question is what the implementation of Count() is for the collection type of Products I guess. `Select(c => new { c.CategoryId, c.Name, c.Products.Count() });` could potentially produce the "appropriate" SQL/Code/etc.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Yes, ProductCount is not stored in the DB. I tried the code above but I cannot get it to work. As written, it returns an anonymous type and it will not compile. If I change it to `c=> new Category` I get "The entity or complex type 'Category' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query." Am I missing something?

Comment: What compile error are you getting? It will return an anonymous type, that is correct. It is the result of a `SELECT` statement in the generated SQL. It should essentially be doing what you would have done in SQL (with a sub query).

Comment: I need to return an IEnumerable<Category> because this is in a service layer. So at the end of the query I am calling ToList(). The error is (types shortened) `Cannot implicitly convert type 'List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'IEnumerable<Category>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`. This is why I tried `c=> new Category`. Not sure where to do the type conversion here.

Comment: I see, well you could try the following: `context.Categories.SortBy(sortByExpression).Skip(startRowIndex).Take(maximumRows)
    .Select(c => new { c.CategoryId, c.Name, ProductCount = c.Products.Count() }).ToList().Select(c => new Category() { CategoryId = c.CategoryId, Name = c.Name, ProductCount = c.ProductCount }).ToList();`. The first `ToList()` will evaluate the SQL, then the `Select` statement is executed in memory allowing you to create complex types, and then finally you create a new `List`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear as enough but if I understood well you want the new column in result for example productCount and you did it with SQL query like below:

```
SELECT c.*, , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Products p WHERE p.categoryId = c.id) AS productCount FROM
Categories c
WHERE <Conditions>
```

Now you want to be able do that using linq(If your question really this), you can do it as below:

```
List<Category> categoryList = (from c in context.Categories let pCount = c.Products.Count() select
new { categoryId = c.CategoryId, CategoryName = c.Name, productCount = pCount})
.OrderBy([sortByExpression]).Skip([startRowIndex]).Take([maximumRows]).ToList();
```

Hope this help.